# Move cursor to the most left part of document?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this very long xml file that I would want be written in a file while keeping its format.

Currently, what is happening is my cursor keeps on moving to the right and does not start at the most left part of the file after the return command.
I have tried using {left %count%} command, this will not solve my problem because the length of each nodes/line varies.

```
Send,`   <span/> TLONG TEXT HERE AND TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON  `  {Return}
Send,`       <span>   TLONG TEXT HERE AND TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON          `  {Return}
Send,`           <span>   TLONG TEXT HERE AND TO SEE WHAT IS GOING ON      `  {Return}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `return` does not mean "next line, carriage return" because in AHK it means "return to the place you were called from" that is, leaving a loop or function, or going back to the thing that called the script (so terminating it).

What you want is to use the next line (linefeed) symbol, `n

Look at the help at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#strings and also https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm